# Laravel 8: after successful log in Auth session destroying on its own whenever I'm trying to redirect it to another route

Tags: laravel-8

web.php
Route::get('/', [AdminLoginController::class, 'index'])->name('admin.login');
Route::post('/login', [AdminLoginController::class, 'login'])->name('admin.login.submit');

Route::group(['middleware' => 'admin.middle' ] , function() {

```
Route::get('/dashboard', [AdminDashboardController::class, 'index'])->name('admin.dashboard');
```

});

AdminLoginController.php

public function login(Request $request)
{

```
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
        'email' => 'required|email:rfc,dns|exists:admins,email',
        'password' => 'required',
    ],[
        'email.required' => "Email is required",
        'email.email' => "Email is invlaid",
        'email.exists' => "Email does not exist",
        'password.required' => "Password is required"
    ]);

    if($validator->fails())
    {
        $this->sendResponse(400,$validator->errors()->first(),[]);
    }
    else
    {
        if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(["email" => $request->email , "password" => $request->password])) {

            $this->sendResponse(
                200,
                "Successfully Logged In",
                [
                'location' => route('admin.dashboard')
            ]);
        
        }
        else {

            $this->sendResponse(
                500,
                "Email or Password is incorrect",
                []);

        }
    }
    
}
```

AdminAuthenticate.php

class AdminAuthentication
{
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
if (Auth::guard('admin')->check())
{

```
        if (Auth::guard('admin')->user()){
            return $next($request);
        }
    }

    return redirect('/admin');
}
```

}

Comment: Please add your `admin.middle` code.

Comment: please check now

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your `sendResponse` is not set corresponding headers (`Set-cookie`)? It looks like you mixing api responses with responses for browser.

Comment: actually i was submitting form through ajax that's why I was using sendResponse method